# select next and previous records in Sequelize based on createdAt

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

**What I want:** fetch one record from the database based on its ID (UUID) and retrieve next and previous records too

**Associations**: `posts N:M categories, posts 1:N comments, posts N:1 users, posts N:M tags, posts 1:N post_views`

**Current solution:**

```
const post = await PostModel.findByPk(id, {
    include: [
      { model: CategoryModel, attributes: ['title'] },
      { model: TagModel },
      { model: CommentModel, include: { model: UserModel } },
      { model: PostViewModel },
      { model: UserModel, attributes: ['fullname', 'id', 'avatar'] }
    ]
  });
const nextPost = await PostModel.findOne({
  where: { createdAt: {
    [Op.gt]: post.createdAt
  }}
const prevPost = await PostModel.findOne({
  where: { createdAt: {
    [Op.lt]: post.createdAt
  }}

});
```

but I think this is not efficient and good.

Comment: if it's still needed.. could you please provided some samples?  are those neighboring posts related? or do you just need the next (even from other users) in db?